# Generational Curses vs Personal Resposibility

Tags: sin, textual-discrepancies, blessings, family, curses

There are numerous passages that support the concept of generational curses - that children will be punished for the sins of their parents.

> [Exodus 20:5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%2020%3A5), [Exodus 34:7](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%2034:7), [Numbers 14:18](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Numbers%2014:18), [Deuteronomy 5:9](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy+5:9) 
> You shall not bow down to them or worship them; for I, the Lord your God, am a jealous God, punishing the children for the sin of the parents to the third and fourth generation of those who hate me,
>
> [Jeremiah 32:18](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=jeremiah%2032%3A18) 
> You show love to thousands but bring the punishment for the parents’ sins into the laps of their children after them. Great and mighty God, whose name is the Lord Almighty,

There are other verses that say that a person will be treated according to their own actions and not the actions of ancestors or descendants.

> [Deuteronomy 24:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy%2024:16) 
> Parents are not to be put to death for their children, nor children put to death for their parents; each will die for their own sin.
>
> [Ezekiel 18:20,30](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=ezekial+18%3A20%2C30) 
> The one who sins is the one who will die. The child will not share the guilt of the parent, nor will the parent share the guilt of the child. The righteousness of the righteous will be credited to them, and the wickedness of the wicked will be charged against them...
>
> “Therefore, you Israelites, I will judge each of you according to your own ways, declares the Sovereign Lord. Repent! Turn away from all your offenses; then sin will not be your downfall.

These seem to me to be in direct conflict. Has there been any scholarship or commentaries that address this difference? A Protestant response would be preferred but I would appreciate an answer from any tradition.

Comment: I will not weigh in on this question, but I will draw your attention to a New Testament passage which parallels quite nicely, I think, the verses you cite. Moreover, the tension, or apparent conflict, in both passages is quite evident. Galatians 6:1-5:  Brethren, even if anyone is caught in any trespass, you who are spiritual, restore such a one in a spirit of gentleness; each one looking to yourself, so that you too will not be tempted.  Bear one another's burdens, and thereby fulfill the law of Christ.

Comment: For if anyone thinks he is something when he is nothing, he deceives himself.  But each one must examine his own work, and then he will have reason for boasting in regard to himself alone, and not in regard to another. For each one will bear his own load." The two concepts of interpersonal accountability and personal responsibility are complementary. No one is an island; no one lives or dies to himself. Each person is also an island and lives and dies to himself. Each statement is true in its own way. It's not a case of either/or, but of both/and. Don

Comment: This is opinion based unless you can scope it to a specific denomination or belief system. You could also approach it from more of a hermeneutics angle, and ask on BH what each verse means.

Comment: The nuance you are missing seems to be that God passes on non-capital "punishment" to several generations, but brings "death" to the individual who sins. The curse over generations is of a different nature than death.

Comment: @Flimzy I rephrased the question to hopefully address your concerns.

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks, but I'm afraid "protestant" isn't really any better than no scope, in this particular case. Protestants are really all over the board on this topic, ranging from Charismatics, who are sometimes criticized for treating every "bad" thing as the result of a curse and/or demon possession, to far more "conservative" denominations which don't believe in curses at all, except as the natural consequences of one's poor decisions.

Comment: @Flimzy Ok. I guess I need to do a little more research and come back here when I have a better grasp on the topic.

Answer (score 3):

Each passage was written for its times and its own purpose.

The threats of intergenerational accountability (Exodus 20:5, Exodus 34:7, Numbers 14:18, Deuteronomy 5:9) were written to make the Jews really think about the consequences of worshipping other gods - they might not have been worried about their own fate, but what about their children and grandchildren?

Ezekiel wrote at a time when Babylon was swallowing up Judah and he was aware of the despair and fatalistic loss of hope felt by his compatriots. As long as they believed that they were being punished for the sins of their forebears, the Jews had no reason for hope or (importantly for Ezekiel) for following him in the worship of Yahweh. Daniel I. Block (*[The Book of Ezekiel: Chapters 1–24](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=j2ZyCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT431&dq=ezekiel%20interpolation&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ_4vW8-jJAhVHw2MKHZ9QDeIQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=%22(b)%20the%20answer%22&f=false)*) says [`(b) The Answer (18:19-20)`] his rejection of any deterministic notion of intergenerational accountability was a response to this. By declaring that a person’s righteousness and wickedness will be credited to that person’s account only, Ezekiel slams the door on the old fatalistic illusion.

Deuteronomy 24:16 is subtly different. This does not talk about whether God will punish children for the sins of their fathers, but is a commandment to the Jews, that they should not do so:

> [Deuteronomy 24:16](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Deuteronomy-Chapter-24/#16): The fathers shall not be put to death for the children, neither shall the children be put to death for the fathers: every man shall be put to death for his own sin.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be overlooking the fact that each of those scriptures have reference to worshipping either God or gods. As you accurately espoused in both Deuteronomy and Ezekiel ***We are responsible for our own decisions***.

where the association of the parents sin and the children's sin connect is in the continuation of false worship. As long as worship of false gods is perpetuated among decedents, God will continue to hold each generation guilty. But the father will not be held guilty if the son after being properly taught decides to follow false gods, nor will the son who returns to worship of the one true God be held responsible for the fathers worship of false gods.

**This is the concept of free will in which God will honor our choices whether good or evil.**

Hope this helps.